How to create a conditional loop with Mono in java?
I need a conditional loop in the reactive pipeline. Aslong as condition is true, it should keep on looping, and once the condition turns false it should stop looping and return whatever value it got from the loop.
Mono.just(new Pair<>(record, order))
            .flatMap(pair -> handleDelayedRoundNumber()
                    .flatMap(roundNumber -> handleProofRequest(pair.first(), pair.second())
                            .doOnSuccess(proof -> new Pair<>(roundNumber < order.clientMetadata().timeout(), proof))
                    )
            ).repeat(result -> result.first() && result.second() != null)
            .flatMap(result -> {
                if(result.second() == null){
                    return Mono.empty();
                }
                return Mono.just(result.second());
            })
            .flatMap(proof -> doStuffWithProof(proof));

I need something that behaves like this. But i cant figure out how to do it.
I think the idea what i want is easier to explain in non-reactor way
Order order = ...;
Record record = ...;
String proof;
do {
   int roundNumber = handleDelayedRoundNumber();
   proof = handleProofRequest(record, order);
while(roundNumber < order.clientMetadata().timeout() && proof == null);

doStuffWithProof(proof);


Could you please explain it in more details? It's unclear what you want to do. Right now it looks like you want just .filter() but I'm sure I'm missing something from your explanation

@IgorArtamonov added more info

Thank you for giving a non-reactive example, that explained the idea. Please see a possible solution below

I think you are looking for something like this:
Flux.concat(
   // run at least once
   handleProofRequest(record, order),

   // just create an infinite flow, like a while loop
   Flux.range(0, Long.MAX_VALUE)
      // concurrency=1 just to make sure you don't do it multiple times in parallel
      .flatMap({ handleDelayedRoundNumber() }, 1)
      // here we check when to complete the processing, like in the while loop
      .takeUntil(roundNumber -> roundNumber < order.clientMetadata().timeout())
      // if the handler returns Empty then it basically loops again
      .flatMap { handleProofRequest(record, order) }
  ) 
   // stops once we've got an element; or nothing if completed because of the timeout
   .next()

   // and the code you have at the bottom
   .filter(pair -> pair.second() != null)
   .map(pair -> pair.second())
   .flatMap(proof -> doStuffWithProof(proof));  


handleProodRequest must run atleast 1 time. Here it seems like it wont be run if roundNumber < timeout

You could use a concat. See updated example
